# WCF Service's Data Gets Refreshed (Deleted) Completely After 15-30 Minutes for No Apparent Reason

Tags: c#, api, wcf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm creating an event-management system. In this system I have a WCF service which loads the events. I have a layered architecture with a repository and service layer. The data is published to an Azure web service app. The data is consumed in a Xamarin.Forms application:

```
public class EventRepository : IEventRepository
    {
        public EventRepository()
        {
            InitializeEvents();
        }
        public List<Event> Events { get; set; }
        private void InitializeEvents()
        {
            if (Events == null)
            {
                Events = new List<Event>()
                {
                    new Event()
                    {
                        EventTitle = "Tom's 14th Birthday Party",
                        EventDescription = "Tom's celebrating his 14th birthday party, come and celebrate with us!",
                        EventGuid = Guid.Parse("258cfa9a-232a-4f36-8eec-010ad072ede3"),
                        Image = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fimg.aws.livestrongcdn.com%2Fls-1200x630%2Fds-photo%2Fgetty%2Farticle%2F251%2F177%2F78054774.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",

                        Time = new TimeSpan(14, 30, 0),
                        Date = new DateTime(2021, 1, 2),
                        Area = "New York, NY",
                        Street = "5 Medburry Place"
                    },
                    new Event()
                    {
                        EventTitle = "Skate Event at Ownen's",
                        EventDescription = "Come to 52 Owen's Park and skate together with us!",
                        EventGuid = Guid.Parse("26ea384f-8fee-4455-8a5f-5b405e07e582"),
                        Image = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwesternnews.media.clients.ellingtoncms.com%2Fimg%2Fphotos%2F2017%2F06%2F11%2FSkate_Competition_002.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
                                                
                        Time = new TimeSpan(8, 30, 0),
                        Date = new DateTime(2021, 3, 12),
                        Area = "Los Angeles, California",
                        Street = "8 Roland Avenue"
                    },
                    new Event()
                    {
                        EventTitle = "Teen Meetup Event",
                        EventDescription = "13-18 year olds - come to this event to meet other teens!",
                        EventGuid = Guid.Parse("ee39dfd5-f220-4111-8b49-bdf554dcce56"),
                        Image = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.thebostoncalendar.com%2Fsystem%2Fevents%2Fphotos%2F000%2F079%2F749%2Foriginal%2Ffellowship2015.jpg%3F1465380904&f=1&nofb=1",
                                               
                        Time = new TimeSpan(11, 0, 0),
                        Date = new DateTime(2021, 2, 5),
                        Area = "Sydney, Australia",
                        Street = "12 Sugar Place",
                    },
                    new Event()
                    {
                        EventTitle = "VIP Lamborghini Event",
                        EventDescription = "Have a lambo? Come to our event!",
                        EventGuid = Guid.Parse("5b7da478-a26c-4bee-8a9d-3bdb1318ed16"),
                        Image = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fag-log.o.auroraobjects.eu%2F04-2017%2Flamborghini_corsa%2F3.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
                                                
                        Time = new TimeSpan(6, 0, 0),
                        Date = new DateTime(2021, 1, 8),
                        Area = "Los Angeles, California",
                        Street = "53 Rodeo Drive"
                    },
                    new Event()
                    {
                        EventTitle = "Jona's 18th Birthday Party",
                        EventDescription = "Jona's celebrating his 18th birthday party, come and celebrate with us!",
                        EventGuid = Guid.Parse("7aaca8b4-ae8d-4075-87cd-6dccc79d1018"),
                        Image = "https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=https%3A%2F%2Fmirageparties.co.uk%2Fwp-content%2Fuploads%2F2019%2F01%2F18th-birthday-party-hero.jpg&f=1&nofb=1",
                                               
                        Time = new TimeSpan(17, 20, 0),
                        Date = new DateTime(2021, 1, 1),
                        Area = "Dunedin, New Zealand",
                        Street = "3 Bird Street"
                    }
                };

                Events[0].EventCode = Events[0].GenerateCode();
                Events[1].EventCode = Events[1].GenerateCode();
                Events[2].EventCode = Events[2].GenerateCode();
                Events[3].EventCode = Events[3].GenerateCode();
                Events[4].EventCode = Events[4].GenerateCode();
            }
        }
        public void AddEvent(Event @event)
        {
            @event.EventGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            @event.Image = "https://static.wixstatic.com/media/be0a80_ab5136b10eec4badbf20309b90932e81.jpg";
            Events.Add(@event);
        }

        public IList<Event> GetAllEvents()
        {
            return Events;
        }
    }
```

```
public class EventService : IEventService
    {
        private readonly IEventRepository _eventRepository;
        public EventService(IEventRepository eventRepository)
        {
            _eventRepository = eventRepository;
        }

        public void AddEvent(Event @event)
        {
            _eventRepository.AddEvent(@event);
        }

        public IList<Event> GetAllEvents()
        {
            return _eventRepository.GetAllEvents();
        }
    }
```

```
 public class EventWCFService : IEventWCFService
    {
        private static IEventService _eventService = new EventService(new EventRepository());
        public void AddEvent(Event @event)
        {
            try
            {
                if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(@event.EventTitle) || @event == null)
                {
                    throw new FaultException("Event name is required");
                }

                _eventService.AddEvent(@event);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                throw new FaultException($"Whoops... Something has gone wrong {exception.Message}");
            }
        }
        public IList<Event> GetAllEvents()
        {
            return _eventService.GetAllEvents();
        }
    }
```

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IEventWCFService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        IList<Event> GetAllEvents();
        [OperationContract]
        void AddEvent(Event @event);
    }
```

Xamarin.Forms:

```
public class EventRepository : IEventRepository
    {
        private readonly ServiceReference1.IEventWCFService eventWCFService;
        public static readonly EndpointAddress EndPoint = new EndpointAddress("(my address)"); // Azure endpoint address
        public EventRepository()
        {
            eventWCFService = new ServiceReference1.EventWCFServiceClient(CreateBasicHttpBinding(), EndPoint);
        }
        public IList<Event> Events { get; private set; }

        // Binding contract
        private BasicHttpBinding CreateBasicHttpBinding()
        {
            BasicHttpBinding httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding()
            {
                Name = "basicHttpBinding",
                MaxBufferSize = BindingConstants.ConstMaxBufferSize,
                MaxReceivedMessageSize = BindingConstants.ConstMaxReceivedMessageSize
            };
            TimeSpan timeOut = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);

            httpBinding.SendTimeout = timeOut;
            httpBinding.OpenTimeout = timeOut;
            httpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = timeOut;

            return httpBinding;
        }

        public async Task AddEventAsync(Event @event)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => { eventWCFService.AddEvent(ConvertToRemoteEvent(@event)); });
        } 

        public async Task<IList<Event>> GetAllEventsAsync()
        {
            Events = new List<Event>();

            var events = await Task.Run(() => { return eventWCFService.GetAllEvents(); });

            foreach (var item in events)
            {
                Events.Add(ConvertToLocalEvent(item)); 
            }

            return Events;
        }

        private Event ConvertToLocalEvent(ServiceReference1.Event remoteEvent)
        {
            return new Event()
            {
                EventTitle = remoteEvent.EventTitle,
                EventDescription = remoteEvent.EventDescription,
                EventGuid = remoteEvent.EventGuid,
                EventCode = remoteEvent.EventCode,
                Image = remoteEvent.Image,

                Time = remoteEvent.Time,
                Date = remoteEvent.Date,
                Area = remoteEvent.Area,
                Street = remoteEvent.Street,
            };
        }

        private ServiceReference1.Event ConvertToRemoteEvent(Models.Event localEvent)
        {
            return new ServiceReference1.Event()
            {
                EventTitle = localEvent.EventTitle,
                EventDescription = localEvent.EventDescription,
                EventGuid = localEvent.EventGuid,
                EventCode = localEvent.EventCode,
                Image = localEvent.Image,

                Time = localEvent.Time,
                Date = localEvent.Date,
                Area = localEvent.Area,
                Street = localEvent.Street,
            };
        }
    }
```

Now - stay with me - **if you close and reopen the application - and add some events - the data stays (it's all good and working)**.

But... after around 10-15 minutes - the data on the remote event service **gets refreshed completely to its original state of the default 5 events.** This means if you create a new event - after 15 minutes - **the data gets completely lost.** Now - it may not be exactly 15 minutes so let's just say it's around 15-30 minutes. This error is strange - I have no idea as to why this is happening. It could be something to do with Azure - but again - I am not entirely sure.

Here is the `EventOverviewViewModel`:

```
 public class EventOverviewViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Event> _events;
        private ObservableCollection<Event> _eventsSignedUp;

        public ICommand EventSelectedCommand => new Command<Event>(OnEventSelectedCommand);

        // FAB stands = 'floating action button'
        public ObservableCollection<Event> Events
        {
            get => _events;
            set
            {
                _events = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(Events));
            }
        }
        public ObservableCollection<Event> EventsSignedUp
        {
            get => _eventsSignedUp;
            set
            {
                _eventsSignedUp = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EventsSignedUp));
            }
        }

        public EventOverviewViewModel(IDialogService dialogService,
                                      IEventService eventService,
                                      IShellNavigationService shellNavigationService,
                                      IThemeService themeService,
                                      ILocalEventDatabase localEventDatabase) : base(dialogService, eventService, shellNavigationService, themeService, localEventDatabase)
        {
            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Event>(this, MessagingCenterMessages.EVENT_SIGNEDUP, (eventFound) => 
            {
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(EventsSignedUp));
            });
        }

        public async Task<EventOverviewViewModel> OnAppearing()
        {
            await LoadData();
            await LoadSQLiteDataToObservableCollection();
            return this;
        }
        private async Task LoadSQLiteDataToObservableCollection()
        {
            try
            {
                var data = await _localEventDatabase.GetRegisteredEventsAsync();

                EventsSignedUp = new ObservableCollection<Event>(data);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _dialogService.ShowAdvancedToast(string.Format($"There was an error loading SQLite: {exception.Message}"), Color.Red, Color.White, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            }
        }

        private async Task LoadData()
        {
            if (Connectivity.NetworkAccess == NetworkAccess.None)
            {
                _dialogService.ShowAdvancedToast(string.Format("Please turn on your internet to use this app."), Color.Red, Color.White, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
            }
            else
            {
                try
                {
                    var data = await _eventService.GetAllEventsAsync();
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    _dialogService.ShowAdvancedToast(string.Format($"There was an error: {exception.Message}"), Color.Red, Color.White, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
                }
            }
        }

        public async void OnEventSelectedCommand(Event @event)
        {
            try
            {
                await _shellNavigationService.NavigateToAsync(nameof(EventDetailView), @event);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

            }
        }
    }
```

On the other hand - my local data service works fine.

I've tried many things - such as resetting the service - redeploying to Azure - and monitoring it. But the bug is still there - I am looking for a solution to this so I can finally finish my application.

*This is my first question here so apologies if it's not 100% right* :)

Thank you,

**EDIT: I am looking for ANY sort of information that may lead me to an ANSWER - any comments are appreciated - I have no idea what the source of the problem is but whoever can help me fix this - I would raise a hat to you!**

Comment: You don't appear to have any backing store for your data and are just storing it in memory.  Whenever your service goes idle you are losing in data that is stored in-memory when the service is spun up again.

Comment: I'm kind of new to WCF - I followed Gill Cleeren's course on it called 'Remote Data Services in Xamarin.Forms' on Pluralsight - could you explain some more as to what you mean by backing store? Could you edit my code so that it has one or offer an answer? Thank you @Jason

Comment: a backing store is permanent storage, typically a database but sometimes just a file.  This is a general programming concept, not anything directly tied to WCF.

Comment: @Jason could you help me implement this? all I know is that is it hosted on an azure web service database... but again - I am not entirely sure what you mean by your answer. this is a remote data service not a local data service? sorry if I sound stupid I am just knew to databases and it is my weak point. I am self taught programmer so I might not be as knowledgeable as most people here.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a free consulting service,  There are thousands of tutorials available on how to create simple databases.  Alternately, you could configure Azure to run your service 24/7 but that might get expensive.